# Issues with Passing Pointers to Function

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I'm trying to write something that will take two command line arguments (a word, and a letter), and remove all instances of that letter from the word. For example, if I pass Hello and e, Hllo should be the resulting String.

I'm trying to do this using pointers, and reducing unnecessary local variables for efficiency. When compiling I'm getting obvious incompatibility warnings, and I know it has something to do with my pointers. If I use local variables and just pass those, everything works perfect - so my understanding of pointers is obviously flawed.

Any pointers (no pun intended) would be greatly appreciated!

```
// Function Prototypes
void remove_all_chars(char *, char *);

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { //Function parameters allow for CLI arguments

    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n", argv[2]);
    char *charTest2 = *argv[2];
    char *strTest = strdup(argv[1]);
    //char strTest[20];
    //char charTest[20];
    //strncpy(strTest, argv[1], 10);
    //strTest[0] = *argv[1];
    remove_all_chars(strTest, charTest2);
    printf("%s", strTest);

    return 0;

}


void remove_all_chars(char *str, char *c) {
    char *pr = str, *pw = str;
    while (*pr) {
        *pw = *pr++;
        pw += (*pw != c);
    }
    *pw = '\0';
}
```

EDIT: After add `char*` to my data types, I end up with the following warnings:

```
Removing3.c:12:8: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'char *' with an
      expression of type 'char'; remove * [-Wint-conversion]
        char *charTest2 = *argv[2];
              ^           ~~~~~~~~
Removing3.c:30:20: warning: comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'char *')
        pw += (*pw != c);
               ~~~ ^  ~
2 warnings generated.
```

EDIT: Here are the warnings

```
Removing3.c:18:19: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of
      type 'char *'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]
        remove_all_chars(strTest, charTest2);
                         ^~~~~~~
                         &
Removing3.c:2:29: note: passing argument to parameter here
void remove_all_chars(char *, char *);
                            ^
Removing3.c:18:28: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of
      type 'char *'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]
        remove_all_chars(strTest, charTest2);
                                  ^~~~~~~~~
                                  &
Removing3.c:2:37: note: passing argument to parameter here
void remove_all_chars(char *, char *);
                                    ^
Removing3.c:19:15: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char' [-Wformat]
        printf("%s", strTest);
                ~~   ^~~~~~~
                %c
Removing3.c:30:20: warning: comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'char *')
        pw += (*pw != c);
               ~~~ ^  ~
4 warnings generated.
```

Comment: What warnings are you getting? Please include them in your question.

Comment: `char` and `char*` are very different types

Comment: Try: 
    char *charTest2 = argv[2];
    char *strTest = argv[1];

Comment: @HarryCutts I've edited my post to include them.

Comment: @UnholySheep I understand that, do you mind explaining how they differ so I can better understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function takes arguments of type `char*`, but your local variables `char charTest2 = *argv[2]; char strTest = *argv[1]` are of type `char`. A variable of type `char` is capable of holding one single character, and your variables will hold the first letter of the respective `argv` then. A `char *`, in contrast, is a pointer to a character in memory; it often points to the first of a sequence of characters, then treated as a "string"; the sequence (i.e. the string) ends with the string termination character `'\0'`, i.e. a `0`-value.

First, change them to `char*`; Second: I'd avoid to change the strings in `argv` directly but rather make a copy:

```
char *strTest = strdup(argv[1]); 
char *charTest2 = argv[2]; // will not be changed; no copy necessary
```

If `strdup` is not available, you could write:

```
char *strTest = malloc(strlen(argv[1])+1);
strcpy(strTest,argv[1]);
```

And you need to change

```
    pw += (*pw != c);
```

into

```
    pw += (*pw != *c);
```

Comment: I've followed your steps using strdup and am now getting 2 warnings. Please see above edit.

`Removing3.c:12:8: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'char *' with an
      expression of type 'char'; remove * [-Wint-conversion]
        char *charTest2 = *argv[2];
              ^           ~~~~~~~~

Removing3.c:30:20: warning: comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'char *')
        pw += (*pw != c);
               ~~~ ^  ~
2 warnings generated.`

Comment: Thanks for your help. More importantly, thanks for explaining why your code works.